# How can I create folder in importing process [python]

Tags: python, path

How can I create a class that creates directories for both with 1. Initial values and 2. input arguments ?

This is my code mypath.py

```
import os

myroot = 'D:\\pet'

class path(object)
    dog = os.path.join(myroot, 'dog')
    cat = os.path.join(myroot, 'cat')

# my 1st question (something like this)
    def __init__(self):
        for directory in dir(self):
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)

# my 2nd question (something like this)
    def append(self, newpath)
        for directory in dir(self):
            newdir = os.path.join(directory, newpath)
            if not os.path.exists(newdir):
                os.makedirs(newdir)

        # update attribute in self
            self.directory = newdir
```

When I do

```
import mypath
```

I can see

```
mypath.dog = 'D:\\pet\\dog'
mypath.cat = 'D:\\pet\\cat'
```

But they are not created, instead I manually have to do like this:

```
os.mkdir(mypath.dog)
os.mkdir(mypath.cat)
```

So my question #1 is

How can I make the class to automatically create every path whenever I import?

and question #2 is

How can I create a sub function .append() so that

```
mypath.append('ishungry')
```

to automatically update all attributes in path so that

```
mypath.dog = 'D:\\pet\\dog\\ishungry'
mypath.cat = 'D:\\pet\\cat\\ishungry'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the logic to make the directories exist in the objects __init__ method; this doesn't run upon import. That's why when you import the module, the directories are not made. To make them, you'd have to create an instance of the 'path' object:

```
import mypath

my_path= mypath.path()
```

Is there a compelling reason to make these directories upon import instead of upon object initialization? It's generally considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to have this type of side effect upon module import.

A cleaner way to do this might be to have an object that handles all the path stuff for you, and to work with that object directly:

```
class PathManager(object):
    """Manages file system paths

    :param root: The base of all paths
    :type root: String

    :param top_dirs: The frist class directories we care about.
    :type top_dirs: List
    """

    def __init__(self, root='D:\\pet', top_dirs=None)
        self.root = root
        self.top_dirs = [] if top_dirs is None else top_dirs
        self._config_dir()

    def _config_dir(self, new_dir=None)
        """Updates all managed paths to contain new_dir"""
        for folder in self.top_dirs:
            if new_dir is not None:
                directory = os.path.join(self.root, folder, new_dir)
            else:
                directory = os.path.join(self.root, folder)
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)

    def append(self, new_dir):
        """Add a new subdirectory to all managed paths, then update
           the list of managed paths"""
        # add new paths to file system
        self._config_dir(new_dir=new_dir)
        # update class to know of update managed paths
        self.top_dirs = [os.path.join(self.root, x, new_dir) for x in self.top_dir]
```

Then use it like:

```
from mypath import PathManager

# Creates the initial paths
path_mgr = PathManager(top_dirs=['dog, 'cat'])

# add a new subdir to managed path
path_mgr.append('ishungry')
```

Comment: Thank you willnx, this is far above my expectation. This helped a lot in learning python, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> NOTE: change slash '\' or '/' according to operative system

mainxD.py

```
import os

class pathmy(object):
    currentfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # get your current folder
    folders = [currentfolder+'/dog', currentfolder+'/cat']

# my 1st question (something like this)
    def __init__(self):
        for x in self.folders:
            if not os.path.exists(x):
                os.makedirs(x)

# my 2nd question (something like this)
    @classmethod
    def addthis(self, newpath):
        newfolder = [x+'/'+newpath for x in self.folders]
        # update attribute in self
        for x in newfolder:
            if not os.path.exists(x):
                os.makedirs(x)
        print 'Okay'

if not __name__ == '__main__':
    pathmy()
```

other.py

```
from mainxD import pathmy
print pathmy.folders
print pathmy.addthis('newfolder')
```